# Set size of view in NIB / XIB file

Tags: ios, xcode5, nib

In Xcode 4, there was a never-quite-fixed bug where Xcode prevented you from resizing views (some silly "Design feature") - you had to make sure you set all the topbar/statusbar/navbar/tabbar to "none" before it would unlock the controls.

XCode 5 appears to have taken this bug ... and extended it!

Now it's completely impossible to edit the size of a UIView in a NIB/XIB file. Nothing I do makes a difference, the dimensions are always readonly. I really, really don't want to write source code (so that our NIB + Storyboards will now always look wrong) to workaround this bug, but I can't find any other way.

Anyone found a workaroind inside Xcode itself?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In the Attributes inspector, in the Simulated Metrics section, change the size to None.  This unlocks the view and you can drag to resize it.

EDIT: As noted in the comments below, in more recent versions of Xcode you must set the attribute to `Freeform`, not `None`.

Comment: In Xcode 6, in the Simulated Metrics section, the size attribute is now 'Freeform' instead of 'None'.

Comment: Hi, Thx. But in xcode 9, must be set in **Freeform**

Answer (score 52):

There is the solution for **XCode 9.0**

Select your view and set simulated Metrics as this :

[image]

After this, you can edit your view's size :

[image]

**DEPRECATED :**

There is the solution for **XCode 8.1**

Select your view and set simulated Metrics as this :

[image]

After this, you can edit your view's size :

[image]

Comment: What units are those, though? And how do you ensure that the size you specify scales to different resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

Such settings:
[image: XIB settings]

makes me possible to change `view` size:
[image: XIB settings]

Xcode version: 5.1 (5B130a)